# How to control CEF3 portions of .NET project using Webdriver2?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chromedriver, regression-testing, qtp

> We have a very large .NET project. This has been E2E/regression tested using QTP for 3 years.

Eventually, our AUT is moving to the WEB. This process is expected to take a couple of years, it will be Angular-JS/HTML5, I have been testing automating a demo angular app using Protractor quite successfully.

In the interim, any new UI development on the App will be done using CEF3 and angular.
I wrote a small test of a pure CEF .NET app to test a theory of testing using chromedriver. This was solved by setting the chrome.exe to be the path to the App.exe and worked quite nicely, but required using chromedriver to start the app.

BUT - we will now be entering the phase of hybrid development, we have the situation where QTP will be kicking off the AUT, and performing some actions on older portions of the UI, but then we will encounter a newer CEF portion which we need to be able to test using chromedriver(well QTP if it could actually cope - which it can't). As a first phase, I need to be able to kick off a CHROME driver test which will perform actions on an already running app where CEF is present.

> Can anyone point me at information about this, please. I have tried extensive googling, but I don't seem to be googling the right questions, just vague hints.

Comment: Please can I ask that any answers are to this thread on the hub and not via webex connect or email. I would like to keep things together, and I already lost one reply via webex from a non-contact.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out UFT 12.54 Patch 4, UFT 14.01, preferably 14.01 as it is latest release for this moment.

Guidance can be found from online help (it works same for CEF and CEFSharp):
https://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.01/UFT_Help/Content/Addins_Guide/Work_with_CEF_Applications.htm